# Fix extracted but not configured package blocker

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

Problems started after an unexpected power loss while executing apt-get dist-upgrade.

When I now run command (as root) **apt-get dist-upgrade** and got the following output:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree.
Status information is read .... Done
Try 'apt-get -f install' to correct this.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6: Depends: but is not installed libgcc1
E: Unmet dependencies. Try to use -f.
```

Then I run **apt-get -f install** and get:

```
 Reading package lists ... Done
 Building dependency tree.
 Status information is read .... Done
 Correcting dependencies ... Done
 The following extra packages will be installed:
   libgcc1
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libgcc1
 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 2 not fully installed or removed.
 Need to get 0 B of archives still 47.9 kB.
 After this operation, 156 kB disk space will be used.
 Would you like to continue? [Y / n] y
 E: Can not get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
 debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: File or directory not found
 dpkg: pre-dependency problem concerning ... / libgcc1_1% 3a4.9.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb which libgcc1: i386 contains:
  libgcc1 depends (in advance) of multiarch-support from
   multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.

 dpkg: error processing the archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
  Pre-dependency problem - libgcc1: i386 is not installed
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
 E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run **dpkg-reconfigure -f libgcc1** i get (also other **dpkg-reconfigure**s will not help):

```
debconf : unable to initialize surface : libgcc1
debconf : ( Can not locate Debconf/FrontEnd/Libgcc1.pm in INC ( You may need to install the Debconf :: Frontend :: libgcc1 module) ( INC contains: /etc/perl/usr/local/ lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl.) at (eval 34)line 2.)
debconf : fall back to the surface : nonInteractive 
/usr/sbin/dpkg -reconfigure : please choose a package that you want to reconfigure
```

What should I try now to solve this problem of this package which is **extracted but not configured**? In the current state there is a circular dependency *libgcc1* and *multiarch-support*.

I would be very glad if you can help me, nothing I know to fix problems with packages helps.

Comment: While im not entirely fluent in Duecth, not many others are.  Could you translate the log file?

Comment: @Theoboldt: You set the language of the messages of any (well-behaved) program to English by setting the environment variable `LC_MESSAGES` to the value `C`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get ...`.

Comment: Thanks Virusboy for updating the content with english translations...
THe problem is; `libgcc1` can not be installed because `multiarch-support` is not ready configured, but `multiarch-support` needs a functional `libgcc1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was impossible to solve this circular dependency. I had to reinstall the operating system to solve the problem.